# How do I import a Facebook album to a website?

Tags: vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been asked to create a Photos page on a website.  The website owner would like to display the albums and photos from their Facebook account to save having to upload twice.

Is this possible and how can it be done?

Comment: Jason, we can't create things for you. If you have a specific question, we can help, otherwise we would expect you to do your research first, and if you encounter any problem with the code we can help you.

Comment: see my answer..this answer for ios but may be helped..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234